# Query Stopped Working Once We Made It A Function

Tags: php

A PHP tutorial gave me the following code to use to do a certain database search. I put it in the content.php file and it was working properly

```
$query = "SELECT * 
         FROM subjects 
         ORDER BY position ASC";
$subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($subject_set);
```

(note, the confirm_query function was the following which it accessed in include.php

```
function confirm_query($result_set){
if (!$result_set) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Afterwards, the tutorial was telling me (for the purpose of making it resusable) to turn the $query into a function in the include.php file

Therefore, in include.php we did this

```
    function get_all_subjects() {
    $query = "SELECT * 
             FROM subjects 
             ORDER BY position ASC";
    $subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    return $subject_set;

}
```

Next, we accessed this function by using the following in the content.php file

```
 $subject_set = get_all_subjects();
```

However, now it said 'database query failed'

So moving the first chunk of code above into the include.php file somehow affected the query

Is that clear?

any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the function ,

he dont know what is  `$connection`  variable,

one option to send the connection as argument to the function

```
function get_all_subjects($connection) {
..........
```

}

and call to function

```
$subject_set = get_all_subjects($connection);
```

look on variables scope [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> Here the `$a` variable will be
>   available within the included b.inc
>   script. However, within user-defined
>   functions a local function scope is
>   introduced. Any variable used inside a
>   function is by default limited to the
>   local function scope. For example:

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
?>
```

> This script will not produce any
>   output because the echo statement
>   refers to a local version of the $a
>   variable, and it has not been assigned
>   a value within this scope. You may
>   notice that this is a little bit
>   different from the C language in that
>   global variables in C are
>   automatically available to functions
>   unless specifically overridden by a
>   local definition. This can cause some
>   problems in that people may
>   inadvertently change a global
>   variable. In PHP global variables must
>   be declared global inside a function
>   if they are going to be used in that
>   function.

Comment: $connection was defined in the original file, does it not carry over into the include.php?

Comment: not in the function, in the function is look for local variable

Comment: No, see http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php for a detailed explanation. Either provide it as a parameter or use the `global` keyword.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but in the tutorial, they didn't have to do this. in the tutorial, the code worked as described in my OP. any explanation?

Comment: one more question...would the problem be solved just as well by making $connection global within the function?      the tutorial is a video from Lynda.com essential training. Here's a link http://www.lynda.com/home/displaycourse.aspx?lpk2=435    however, you won't be able to see inside the tutorial because it's pay per view

Comment: yes its another option , i wrote in my answer the common solution, pepole avoid using global, but its work too

Comment: thanks, has php changed? is there any reason why the original code worked for the guy who did the tutorial?

Comment: no i dont think its changed, maybe have a mistake in the tutorial i dont see it i cant say

Comment: the guy corrected the problem later in the tutorial...:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah yup.. The problem is that in the function you have local scope of action so the variables which are outside the scope can't be referenced. They are given by value.. You can add $connection variable as a param to your function

Comment: the connection had worked before moving it into the include.php

Answer (score -2):

If you db connection is handled by a separate file i.e. "connect.php" you must include it within all subsequent functions like this:

```
require "./connect.php";
```

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted.  While it isn't the best solution, it does move the DB connect stuff to the local function that needs it.  It is, however, much nicer not to break/create db connections with every function.  On some DB engines, closing the connection causes the result set to be lost, so I'd discourage it.